# How can I add a tag to a key in boto (Amazon S3)?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I am trying to tag a key that I've uploaded to S3. In the same below I just create a file from a string. Once I have they key, I'm not sure how to tag the file. I've tried Tag as well as TagSet.

```
from boto.s3.bucket import Bucket
from boto.s3.key import Key
from boto.s3.tagging import Tag, TagSet

k = Key(bucket)
k.key = 'foobar/somefilename'
k.set_contents_from_string('some data in file')

Tag(k, 'the_tag')
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As far as I can see in the docs, a [setTags-method](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.set_tags) is only available on a bucket level and not on individual keys. Therefore you cannot set different tags to your uploaded file, but you would have to do this on the containing bucket.

Comment: This is correct.  S3 only supports tags at the bucket level, not on individual objects.  These tags are mainly used for the purpose of cost allocation and tracking as described in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/getbill.html#allocation

Comment: this accepted answer was correct at the time but should now be unaccepted; as Googling this still leads here as the number 1 search result, and it is now wrong and misleading.

Answer (score 25):

S3 has since added [object level tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-tagging.html). You can [get](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object_tagging) and [set](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object_tagging) them with [boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

These are considerably more versatile than metadata:

- They can be added and modified without copying the object.
- They can be used as filters in lifecycle management rules.
- They can be used to control access to objects.

Comment: I am using boto3 and also wish to tag my objects. I found this https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object_tagging . However AWS says you need to use the Content-MD5 HTTP header when performing this operation.

Thing is, I am confused. Does it want the MD5 of the object I am tagging? Of my request? If it is of my request, how do that? my request is represented as a Python dictionary, how can I MD5 that. Any help or suggestions here?

Comment: @PeteJirak ContentMD5 isn't a required field there. You can leave it out if you like. Otherwise, its use is explained more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html

Answer (score 25):

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    region_name='region-name',
    aws_access_key_id='aws-access-key-id',
    aws_secret_access_key='aws-secret-access-key',
)

get_tags_response = s3_client.get_object_tagging(
    Bucket='your-bucket-name',
    Key='folder-if-any/file-name.extension',
)

put_tags_response = s3_client.put_object_tagging(
    Bucket='your-bucket-name',
    Key='folder-if-any/file-name.extension',    
    Tagging={
        'TagSet': [
            {
                'Key': 'tag-key',
                'Value': 'tag-value'
            },
        ]
    }
)
```

Comment: Note, `put_object_tagging` will overwrite the _entire_ `TagSet` which may or may not be desired. If you simply want to add key/value tag pair(s) to the existing `TagSet`, you could first `get_object_tagging`, create an updated dict, then put the result on the object.

Answer (score -1):

While S3 "tags" are only at the bucket-level, each key in a bucket can have arbitrary "metadata" associated with it, which are key-value pairs themselves. See the [boto documentation](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.set_metadata):

```
k.set_metadata('key', 'value')
value = k.get_metadata('key') # prints 'value'
```

Comment: this has changed now. And S3 tags are now available at the object level.