# Tagging s3 in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to create some s3 buckets and Objects using boto3 then add some tags ( object tagging). I then want to use IAM to control access on these objects using these tags. I am unable to find the right syntax. 
I am using create_buckets.py ( to create buckets and objects) and then list_objects.py to list them.

Really appreciate if someone can help me with the syntax to add multiple tags to objects and buckets.

**create_buckets.py**

```
import boto3
from random import randint
import json 
session = boto3.session.Session()
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
state=["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado","Connecticut"]
for x in state:
  bucket_name = x.lower() + '-season-' + str(randint(0, 10000))
  s3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)       
    s3.Object(bucket.name,'hello.txt').put(Body=open('/tmp/hello.txt','rb'))  
    copy_source={ 'Bucket':bucket.name,'Key':'hello123.txt'}
```

**list_objects.py**

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)  
    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
      print(' ' + obj.key)
```

Comment: Is this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827196/how-can-i-add-a-tag-to-a-key-in-boto-amazon-s3

Comment: i don't think. The documentation says tag_set
(list) --
(dict) --
Key (string) --
Name of the tag.
Value (string) --
Value of the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not define tag during uploading object. Here is what I got when I tried to set tag during upload.

[image]

[does not appear to be a valid way to specify a tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56351011/3288890)

But there is way around,

Upload the object and then set the tag once the object is uploaded. Here is complete working example

```
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
client = boto3.client('s3')


def upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name=None):
    """Upload a file to an S3 bucket

    :param file_name: File to upload
    :param bucket: Bucket to upload to
    :param object_name: S3 object name. If not specified then file_name is used
    :return: True if file was uploaded, else False
    """
    # If S3 object_name was not specified, use file_name
    if object_name is None:
        object_name = file_name

    # Upload the file
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
with open("./test.txt", "rb") as f:

    s3.upload_fileobj(f, "config-bucket-name", "test.txt",
      ExtraArgs={
        'Metadata': {'mykey': 'myvalue'}
        })


# set tag once object upload to s3
response = client.put_object_tagging(
    Bucket='config-bucket-name',
    Key='test.txt',
    Tagging={
        'TagSet': [
            {
                'Key': 'ENV',
                'Value': 'Prod'
            },
             {
                'Key': 'type',
                'Value': 'txt'
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Only question i have is it possible to use boto3.resource OR TagSet has to use boto3.client

Comment: `Resources represent an object-oriented interface to Amazon Web Services (AWS). They provide a higher-level abstraction than the raw, low-level calls made by service clients. `
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html